# Rusty find any info?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I recently found an old bicycle frame buried on family property. I have been researching for a week now and still don't have the make, model or year. If anyone has any information at all it would be greatly appreciated.
Chris Vecchio

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, post a photo from the side. Right angle, full bicycle frame in the photo. Also, try to find any markings stamped in the steel. Even if you can't read them, they may help people to find out what it is. And don't try to renovate it yourself *unless you know dang well* how to do it. If you don't, ask :)

Comment: It's pretty old!  I see unusual kinked rear dropouts, and a stop on the left chainstay for a band or hub brake.  The cranks also look particularly pre WW2.  I hope you have more bits than just the frame - a fork would be helpful.   Otherwise fabbing all the missing parts will take you a long time and lots of money/effort.

Comment: I'm sure there's more parts there I happened to find it as I was leaving and was in a hurry was going to work....plan on going back out in the next couple days and looking.

Comment: Those rear dropouts look crimped in not welded/brazed.  That's not a good sign.

Comment: I wonder if I take the sprocket off if the number would be right there